# ShedLock - Not Executing

Tags: shedlock

I am using shedlock library 4.20.0.

```
net.javacrumbs.shedlock shedlock-spring 4.20.0 net.javacrumbs.shedlock shedlock-provider-jdbc-template 2.1.0
```

The scheduler job is,

```
@scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
@SchedulerLock(name = "TaskScheduler__scheduledTask", lockAtLeastForString = "PT5M", lockAtMostForString = "PT14M")
public void reportCurrentTime() {
LockAssert.assertLocked();
log.info("The time is now {} {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()), dataSource);
}
```

It shows @SchedulerLock as deprecated.

And the spring boot class,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT30S")
public class DMSCaseEmulatorSpringApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DMSCaseEmulatorSpringApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

When i execute the spring boot class, it triggers shedlock and creates a record in database table but in logs i keep getting as below,

```
19:54:39.188 [scheduling-1] DEBUG n.j.s.c.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor - Locked TaskScheduler__scheduledTask.
19:54:39.188 [scheduling-1] INFO u.g.h.c.d.s.ScheduledTasks - The time is now 19:54:39 HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)
19:54:39.205 [scheduling-1] DEBUG n.j.s.c.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor - Unlocked TaskScheduler__scheduledTask.
19:54:44.065 [scheduling-1] DEBUG n.j.s.c.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor - Not executing TaskScheduler__scheduledTask. It's locked.
19:54:49.062 [scheduling-1] DEBUG n.j.s.c.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor - Not executing TaskScheduler__scheduledTask. It's locked.
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by `lockAtLeastForString = "PT5M"` By specifying that, you are saying that the lock should be held at least for 5 minutes even if the task finishes sooner.

Regarding the Deprecation warning, please consult the JavaDoc.